# function in data-ng-class not getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a basic project in Angular. I want to color the list items based on the value returned by a function that is called in data-ng-class.

Here is my partial html file.

```
<div>
    Rooms:<ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li style="display:inline-block; padding:20px;" 
            data-ng-repeat="room in SingleDetailedCtrl.singleRooms"
            data-ng-class="getClass('room')">
    {{ room }}
        </li>
    </ul>

    To go back <a ui-sref="plan">click here</a>
</div>
```

The corresponding controller:

```
myApp.controller("SingleDetailedController", function ($log) {
    var singleSelf = this;
    this.singleRooms = ["f1-101", "f1-110", "f2-203", "f3-321", "f3-302"];
    this.sa = ["f1-101", "f2-203", "f3-302"];
    this.sna = ["f1-110", "f3-321"];
    this.getClass = function (room) {
        console.log("sdc");
        var color = red;
        angular.forEach(singleSelf.singleRooms, function (value, key) {
            if (value == room) {
                console.log("sdc if");
                color = green;
            }
        });
        return color;
    };
});
```

The console output I am expecting is not being generated. So, that's how I understood `getClass()` function isn't being called.

I have looked at different questions with the same problem. My code seems to be fine to me but it is not working.

I greatly appreciate any help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use controller instance i.e. `SingleDetailedCtrl` with method

```
<li style="display:inline-block; padding:20px;" 
    data-ng-repeat="room in SingleDetailedCtrl.singleRooms"
    data-ng-class="SingleDetailedCtrl.getClass('room')">
{{ room }}
</li>
```

Comment: @MiguelLattuada, OP must be using it, otherwise he could have got the error in `data-ng-repeat` also

Answer (score 0):

A few minor errors

- The main one is the use of colons for room when passing to getClass method in data-ng-class
- The color red should be a string.

Below is a working code. (Pardon me for adding everything to $scope. Passing the instance of controller around does not make sense it)

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("SingleDetailedController", function($log, $scope) {
    var singleSelf = this;
    $scope.singleRooms = ["f1-101", "f1-110", "f2-203", "f3-321", "f3-302"];
    $scope.sa = ["f1-101", "f2-203", "f3-302"];
    $scope.sna = ["f1-110", "f3-321"];
    $scope.getClass = function(room) {
      console.log("sdc");
      var color = "red";

      angular.forEach($scope.sna, function(value, key) {
        if (value == room) {
          color = "green";
        }
      });
      
      return color;
    };

  });
```

```css
.red{
  background-color: red;
} 


.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SingleDetailedController">
  Rooms:
  <ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li style="display:inline-block; padding:20px;" data-ng-repeat="room in singleRooms" data-ng-class="getClass(room)">
      {{ room }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  To go back <a ui-sref="plan">click here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Same thing can be achieved using controller instance

Comment: I never said no. I find using $scope much more easy to follow.